# Retrieve the same size of images after the grid layout changes

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: 2X5 matrix in which images are not displayed properly][image: 3X3 image matrix]I am changing the layout of my uniformgrid from 3X3 to 2X5. When i am changing from 3X3 to 2X5 the images stretch to the width of uniformgrid but height is getting halved as shared in the attachments.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ImageList1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ImageDisplay" Height="350" Width="825"
        xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
        >
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                    <Label Content="Select the display format:" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSelect" Width="100" Margin="-400,-30,0,10" Height="20" SelectionChanged="CmbSelect_SelectionChanged" >
                        <ComboBoxItem>2X2</ComboBoxItem>
                        <ComboBoxItem>3X3</ComboBoxItem>
                    </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>

              <ListBox Name="UniformGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList1}" >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                            <UniformGrid  Rows="{Binding Path=GridRow, Mode=TwoWay}" Columns="{Binding Path=GridColumn, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="800" Height="500"/>

                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0.5">

                                <Image Source="{Binding Path}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>

                              <TextBlock Background="Black" Foreground="White" Height="18" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,4">
                                <TextBlock Name="ImageName" Margin="0,0,0,1" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                                <TextBlock Name="ImageType" Margin="0,0,0,2" Foreground="LightGoldenrodYellow" FontSize="11">
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Type: {0}">
                                            <Binding Path="Extension" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="ImageSize" Margin="0,0,0,3" Foreground="Violet">
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="Size: {0} Bytes">
                                            <Binding Path="Size"/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                              </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
namespace ImageList1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private bool handle = true;
        int index = 1;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
            Window_Loaded();
        }



        public void Window_Loaded()
        {

            // string folderName = "Wallpapers";
            //string folderpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\ImageList1\ImageList1\Wallpapers");

            ObservableCollection<ImageDetails> images = new ObservableCollection<ImageDetails>();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                ImageDetails id = new ImageDetails()
                {
                    Path = file,
                    FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file),
                    Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)
                };

                BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                img.BeginInit();
                img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                img.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Absolute);
                img.EndInit();
                id.Width = img.PixelWidth;
                id.Height = img.PixelHeight;
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                id.Size = fi.Length;
                images.Add(id);
            }


            UniformGrid.ItemsSource = images;

            UniformGrid.SelectedItem = UniformGrid.Items[index];
            UniformGrid.ScrollIntoView(UniformGrid.Items[index]);

        }

        private void CmbSelect_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
            handle = !cmb.IsDropDownOpen;
            Handle();
        }



        private void Handle()
        {
            switch (cmbSelect.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(new string[] { ": " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last())
            {
                case "2X2": 
                             dynamic_Layout _layout = new dynamic_Layout(2, 5);
                             this.rootGrid.DataContext = _layout;
                             break;
                case "3X3":

                             dynamic_Layout _layout1 = new dynamic_Layout(3, 3);
                             this.rootGrid.DataContext = _layout1;
                             break;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

dynamic_Layout Class:

```
namespace ImageList1
{
    public class dynamic_Layout : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        int _gridRow;
        int _gridColumn;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int GridRow
        {

            get
            {
                return _gridRow;
            }
            set
            {
                _gridRow = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GridRow"));
                }
            }
        }

        public int GridColumn
        {

            get
            {
                return _gridColumn;
            }
            set
            {
                _gridColumn = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GridColumn"));
                }
            }
        }


        public dynamic_Layout(int columns, int rows)
        {

            this.GridColumn = columns;
            this.GridRow = rows;

        }
    }



}
```

Expected result : The layout is changing from 3X3 to 2X5 as expected but the images are not displayed properly.

Actual result: Image is attached.

Comment: Can you replace the `StackPanel` inside the `ItemTemplate` with a `Grid` with two rows and check.

Comment: Coiuld you also show some code-behind like CmbSelect_SelectionChanged and your viewmodel class?

Comment: Not working @Mat J

Comment: Its not really following mvvm pattern as i am a beginner with wpf and have messed up with mvvm. Sure i will post the class which is used to set the rows and columns. @CorentinPane (Most of the code is in code behind)

Comment: Can you try by removing the ```Width="800" Height="500"``` from your ```UniformGrid``` markup?

Comment: If i remove it each of the image occupies the entire page and a scroll view is created@CorentinPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I can see with the XAML code you posted is that you are specifying both a Width and Height for the UniformGrid that hosts the images. This also constrains both dimensions of the ListBoxItems.  So, if you specify 800 x 500 for a 3x3 grid with 8 items, each item has an aspect ratio of 8:5 (8/3:5/3); for a 2x2 grid displaying the same number of items, each item has an aspect ratio of 16:5 (8/2:5/4).  Since the ListBox item can't uniformly stretch to fit both aspect ratios, the items are cut off. By changing this line:

```
<UniformGrid  Rows="{Binding Path=GridRow, Mode=TwoWay}" Columns="{Binding Path=GridColumn, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="800" Height="500"/>
```

to this:

```
<UniformGrid  Rows="{Binding Path=GridRow, Mode=TwoWay}" Columns="{Binding Path=GridColumn, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="800"/>
```

the ListBox items are constrained in only the Width dimension, and are free to fill the height dimension so that the entire item is displayed.

Result 3x3:
[image: 3x3]

Result 2x2:
[image: 2x2]

A further improvement is to use a grid and bind the width of the UniformGrid to the rootGrid ActualWidth.  This allows the ListBox and ListBoxItems to dynamically resize with the window.

```
<Window x:Class="ImageList1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ImageDisplay" Height="350" Width="825"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    >
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Select the display format:"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSelect" Width="100"  Height="20" SelectionChanged="CmbSelect_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="0" >
                    <ComboBoxItem>2X2</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>3X3</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
          <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="UniformGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList1}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid  Rows="{Binding Path=GridRow, Mode=TwoWay}" Columns="{Binding Path=GridColumn, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="{Binding ElementName=rootGrid, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel Margin="0.5" >

                          <Image Source="{Binding Path}"  />

                          <TextBlock Background="Black" Foreground="White" Height="18" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,4">
                              <TextBlock Name="ImageName" Margin="0,0,0,1" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                              <TextBlock Name="ImageType" Margin="0,0,0,2" Foreground="LightGoldenrodYellow" FontSize="11">
                                  <TextBlock.Text>
                                      <MultiBinding StringFormat="Type: {0}">
                                          <Binding Path="Extension" />
                                      </MultiBinding>
                                  </TextBlock.Text>
                              </TextBlock>
                              <TextBlock Name="ImageSize" Margin="0,0,0,3" Foreground="Violet">
                                  <TextBlock.Text>
                                      <MultiBinding StringFormat="Size: {0} Bytes">
                                          <Binding Path="Size"/>
                                      </MultiBinding>
                                  </TextBlock.Text>
                              </TextBlock>
                          </TextBlock>
                      </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a couple of assumptions about your intended solution:

1. The image must be displayed completely, but scaled to fit entirely on the screen at once.
2. The image info bar should always be displayed

### What's Wrong

The Image is allowed to grow to fill the space horizontally, and nothing is stopping it from growing vertically to maintain aspect ratio. StackPanel does not constrain it's child objects in the direction of stacking - so there is an infinite amount of space to expand into (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f09d301-0e5a-4cb6-bb75-71cd1cdae5c4/fixing-stackpanels-maxheight-to-containing-control?forum=wpf)

### How To Fix It

Instead of a StackPanel, you need a control that will restrict itself to the container it is in - this could be a Grid, or a DockPanel, or something else. Using a DockPanel, I would dock the TextBlock to the bottom (`DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"` on the TextBlock element). This also means that it needs to be the first child of the DockPanel as children need to be in the direction that you want them docked. The reason that the TextBlock docks before the Image is that you want to set `LastChildFill="True"` on the DockPanel, so the last item in the panel will try to fill up the remaining available space - unlike the StackPanel, which will grow to accommodate its children.

Finally, remove all the alignment and stretching instructions on the Image. The default behaviour does what you want more.

These changes would mean replacing your StackPanel XAML with:

```
<DockPanel Margin="0.5" LastChildFill="True">

    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Black" Foreground="White" Height="18" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,4">
        <TextBlock Name="ImageName" Margin="0,0,0,1" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="ImageType" Margin="0,0,0,2" Foreground="LightGoldenrodYellow" FontSize="11">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Type: {0}">
                    <Binding Path="Extension" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="ImageSize" Margin="0,0,0,3" Foreground="Violet">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="Size: {0} Bytes">
                    <Binding Path="Size"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </TextBlock>

    <Image DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Source="{Binding Path}"/>

</DockPanel>
```

### Code Review

Your dynamic_layout class doesn't need to have INotifyPropertyChanged on it. The properties are only being set in the constructor, and are never changed after being databound. The whole object is replaced by a new dynamic_layout when you change the dropdown list. For the same reason, the binding in XAML doesn't need to be TwoWay since the value is not updated in those bindings.